# How to get SalesForce picklist dependency mapping in Javascript

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I am using SalesForce API in Javascript to describe a picklist that have dependency control field.

My pick is given to me in an array like this:

```
let picklistValues = [
  {
    "active": true,
    "defaultValue": false,
    "label": "1111111111111",
    "validFor": "gfAA",
    "value": "1111111111111"
  },
  ..... // many more
]
```

My control field is returned to me like this:

```
let controlValues = [
  {
    "active": true,
    "defaultValue": false,
    "label": "aaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "validFor": null,
    "value": "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
  }
]
```

My question is how do I decode the validFor mapping so I can correctly map the 2 list?

Preferably I need a function like this:

```
let controlValue = "aaaaaaaaaaaa";
let validPicklistValues = getValidPicklistValues(controlValue, picklistValues, controlValues );
```

I tried search online but I didn't find anything in javascript, I did however find this code in C#, which I can not use and don't know how to convert.  Please help.

http://titancronus.com/blog/2014/05/01/salesforce-acquiring-dependent-picklists-in-apex/

Comment: Have you ever figured it out? there is a horrible java sample here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm